# How to go from uml to app in zope (plone)

Tags: uml, plone, zope

I have watched [this keynote](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=6297126166376226181&ei=KMNuS97rJYToqALN6IjnBg&q=better+web+apps) that talk about develop an app based on an UML model, but I can't find any tutorial or docs about it.

Do you know any tutorial or documentation to help me?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [ArchGenXML](http://plone.org/products/archgenxml).

> ArchGenXML is a code generator. It builds on architecture-centric, model-based and test-driven development. Generates Python code from UML-Models (XMI-Format). It's optimized for the generation of code based on the Archetypes framework.

Documentation about using it with Plone (Zope) can be found [here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/using-archgenxml).

Answer (score 1):

As Aussie says, ArchGenXML is the way to go - I use it a lot.  But use [Paster](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/use-paster) and Zopeskel too.  Create an "egg" skeleton as documented in the link (use the "archetype" template), then create your model (A .zargo file) in the main code directory (ie, the directory containing config.py).

This way ArchgenXML (AGX) will create everything as appropriate for an egg.

Answer (score -2):

UML (Unified Modeling Languge) - is a modeling language.
Is used to specify, visualize, modify, construct and document the artifacts of an object-oriented software intensive system under development.

Refer to here.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language][1]

If you searched using "UML" you'll find a bunch of result that will help you.

As soon as you will understand the concept of UML and know how to create UML diagrams then there's no more problem creating your app based on your model.

Very best,

Comment: I know about uml. I wan't to know how to go from uml to a webapp, like the video I link shows. You have to see the video that I link.